# How to list all direct and indirect subtypes in a hierarchy stored in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am facing a very general problem. I have a large object hierarchy the relation between each object type is stored in DB table(id, name,supertype_id). Now if I have a hierarchy A<-B<-C<-D. How can I list all subtypes of B. Not only those directly related and of course B can have many direct subtypes not only C and C also can have many subtypes and so on.

Now I now I can fetch all data and process it outside the DB but how would I do it using SQL procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is a good resource](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/). MySQL isn't great with hierarchies but it can be done with a bit of work.

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot. The only subject that is not mentioned there is will it still work if you modify the hierarchy and the statement that if id< id2 then id isParent OR isSibling is no longer true. For example you add a new subtype in the middle.

Comment: As far as I can tell it will, though I have not done such a thing in my use of it.